# Can hamachi clients communicate in gateway network type

Tags: vpn, hamachi

We have a hamachi **gateway** network type vpn. Can 2 hamachi clients connected to this vpn communicate with each other?

I can ping gateway from my client. Gateway can ping clients. But I cannot ping clint to client.

---

10.0.0.1 = gateway ip

10.0.0.30 = client1 ip

10.0.0.31 = client2 ip

---

gateway <-> client1 OK

gateway <-> client2 OK

client1 <-> client2 NO PING

---

Is it possible in gateway network type, or another type should be used for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

Go to the command line and run

```
ipconfig /all
```

then look at "IP Routing Enabled", you MUST have that as YES, otherwise, 
nothing else matters.

If worse comes to worse, you can use `ROUTE -p ADD` commands on each machine to point them to each other; however, there are caveats / AKA other details you must check which are specific to hamachi software:

- Has either client ever been evicted from the network in the logmein software?
- What are your windows firewall settings?
- What is your subscription level with logmein?
- Did you earlier have "hub-and-spoke" set up with either of these systems and then change to gateway mode without restarting?